# ¿Cómo se puede decir "on fire" en español?

Tags: traducción, coloquialismos, solicitud-de-término, españa

Últimamente es un no parar: todo el mundo usa expresiones inglesas en su día a día y he de reconocer que algunas de ellas me gustan mucho y confieso que las uso de vez en cuando.

La que tengo estos días en mente es *on fire*:

> Juan está ***on fire*** últimamente: le han ofrecido un trabajo muy bueno, le tocó la lotería y arde en deseos de colaborar en Spanish Stack Exchange.

O:

> Me siento ***on fire*** esta noche, soy todo ocurrencias.

Básicamente, se usa esta expresión para designar que alguien está en un estado pletórico, atravesando una racha especialmente positiva en uno o distintos aspectos de su vida.

En España yo diría cosas como:

- Pletórico
- A tope (bastante coloquial)
- Enchufado

Pero así y todo tengo mis dudas de que esté traduciendo enteramente el concepto. ¿Qué os parece? ¿Qué palabra o expresión traduciría el concepto más verazmente en España? ¿Y cuál se usa en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: Cuando hablas de "traducir el concepto", ¿te refieres realmente a una traducción, así como para quien no entienda la idea, o a una expresión española que se pueda usar en reemplazo de la inglesa? Aquí en Argentina decimos "on fire" sin más.

Comment: @pablodf76 me refiero a traducir algo que exprese el mismo significado, por ejemplo por si estoy hablando con, qué sé yo, mi abuela :)

Comment: Haría falta un corpus actualizado de menciones de *on fire*, supongo. Para mí la idea es una mezcla entre "enchufado" y "con todo a favor".

Comment: @pablodf76 - Creo que lo que fedorqui busca es un **equivalente** de la expresión "on fire," tal y como se usa en español, pero del **español puro**.  (A fin de cuentas, aunque "on fire" sí se puede usar en inglés, no es súper común.)

Comment: No es suficiente para una respuesta, pero "estar inspirado" y "sentirse bárbaro."

Comment: ¿Se cuenta con un recurso parecido al Urban Dictionary en español?  ¿Diccionario de modismos?  ¿Libro de sinónimos (*thesaurus*)?

Comment: @aparente001 no me consta otro que [asihablamos](http://www.asihablamos.com/). Está bastante bien, pero está lejos de los estándares de Urban Dictionary.

Comment: En México le decimos "me siento bien vergas" :')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paradójicamente la traducción literal "estar que arde (o que quema)" se refiere a situaciones tensas donde se han *acalorado* los ánimos y los participantes están enfadados o directamente peledos (o peleándose).

Yo apostaría por la expresión "estar que se sale", que siempre he entendido como "que se (sobre)sales del baremo o de las tablas para medir/comparar'. Es decir, eres un fuera de serie.

> Juan está **que se sale** últimamente: le han ofrecido un trabajo muy bueno, le tocó la lotería y arde en deseos de colaborar en Spanish Stack Exchange.
>
> Estoy **que me salgo** esta noche, soy todo ocurrencias.

Otra posibilidad podría ser "estar en racha". Si tienes una racha de buena suerte todo te sale bien.

En ocasiones he oído utilizar también "estar sembrado", pero para mi esto es más como "tener muchas y muy buenas ocurrencias" pero no necesariamente "aciertos", así que no sé si este último es la mejor posibilidad para "on fire".

Comment: La mayoría de las expresiones relacionadas con fuego/calor y emoción en inglés tradicionalmente también refieren a la ira o el deseo. Solo hace poco adquirió la expresión *on fire* (encendido) el significado de con buena suerte (como una extensión deportista de *to warm up* o *calentarse*. Uno no juega bien mientras se calienta, pero después juegas bien y cuando estás ardiendo pues ya tiene sentido), y también *flaming* (*llameante*) que significa un hombre homosexual muy efeminado.

Comment: Me gusta "estar en racha," aunque también uno puede tener *mala racha*.

Answer (score 7):

Aunque ya ha sido comentada brevemente por Diego, yo voy a incidir en la expresión ***en racha***, ya que es la que más me pega a mí como traducción:

> **[racha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UzozVMf)**
>
> Quizá del ár. *ráǧǧa* 'sacudida', 'agitación', 'tormenta'.
>
> 1. f. Ráfaga de aire.
> 2. f. En cualquier actividad, período breve de fortuna o desgracia.

Como mencionó aparente en un comentario, efectivamente una racha puede ser un periodo de fortuna o desgracia, así que dependerá del contexto dilucidar si se trata de uno u otro. Sin embargo, yo la expresión "estar en racha" la asocio automáticamente con "buena suerte". Para la mala suerte yo diría que "está pasando una mala racha".

Encuentro un caso en el CORDE que incluye una explicación adicional (negritas mías):

> *Como puntero inicia dicha temporada, recorriendo los principales ruedos españoles **en racha de éxito**, y presentándose en la plaza Monumental de Madrid el 19 de junio, alternando con Luis Rivas y Pablo Lalanda en la lidia de novillos de Antonio Pérez.*
>
> José María de Cossío, "Los mejores toreros de la historia", c 1966 (España).

Sin embargo, dicha expresión se acorta ya en la actualidad, manteniendo un sentido positivo:

> *Prescindir en aquel momento crucial de un jugador **en racha** fue el principio del fin de las ilusiones barcelonistas.*
>
> La Vanguardia, 21/05/1994 : Al equipo azulgrana le falló la mentalización.
>
> ---
>
> *Con todo, parece un hombre serio. Y un actor que sigue **en racha**.*
>
> La Razón, 01/12/2004 : Nicolas Cage: "Tras 25 años de carrera he conseguido que el cine aún no me aburra."

Por los ejemplos que he encontrado (sobre todo en prensa) se usa mucho en el ámbito deportivo, aunque también se puede usar en otros, como es el caso del último ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

No puedo hablar por Hispanoamérica pero en realidad son extranjerismos que están muy mal acostumbrados a usarse en el día a día del español.

Naturalmente se conoce como *estar que se sale,* pero eso al menos en mi país no es idiomático. Acá generalmente lo usan tal cual pero con interpretación de *está que arde.*

Si bien esta última forma conlleva la connotación de *esto va a estar muy bueno,* muy rara vez se les atribuye a las personas cuando están de muy mal humor.

De cualquier forma, este *slang* es figurativo y se entiende como *desempeñar increíblemente bien.*

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no se utiliza el verbo estar. Más bien el verbo tener.

Tener una buena racha, estar de buena racha, seguir de buena racha, estar de buena racha, pero no " *estar de racha* ".

Respecto a la forma de expresar la locución '**on fire**', emplearía " estar que ardes", en ese sentido de pletórico, a tope, en tu mejor momento, con ánimo, mucha energía, etc, etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/24899)